# State and Country picklist feature - issue after converting data

Tags: soql

I have enabled State and Country picklist feature in my org. 
After performing step 3.**Convert your data.** I see that the billingcountry value has been changed from "USA" to "United States" on detail page of the record.

But when I query the same record using SOQL query as shown below -

```
select billingcountry, billingcountrycode from Account where id = '001i000002BRpnX'
```

I see old value "USA" in BillingCountry field instead of new value "United States".

Any clue on this..

Comment: i guess it always billingcountry = United States and billingcountrycode = USA this is how it should be

Comment: Looks like you might have mapped the address picklist incorrectly. Check value of `BillingCountryCode` field.

Comment: BillingCountryCode value is "US". And have not done any mapping for this.